# Ext4 with LUKS explorer for Windows

Tags: windows, encryption, ext4, disk, luks

What is the easiest way to use an external drive with LUKS encryption and EXT4 file system in Windows ?

Ext2read have support for LUKS ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/584883/how-can-i-access-volumes-encrypted-with-luks-dm-crypt-from-windows